# How can I set background color when take transparency image from gallery

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to set the background color of an image when take an image from the gallery because if i take transparency image it set automatically black background behind image.

[image]

But if i keep transparency image in Resources-->drawable folder then it show 
given red background

```
 <Grid Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor=">
    <Image x:Name="RestaurantImage" Source="trans.png" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
 </Grid
```

[image]
This is my take image code :

```
private async void ImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           string action = await UserDialogs.Instance.ActionSheetAsync("PickPhoto", "Cancel", null, null, "Take Photo", "Pick From Gallery");
           MediaFile file = null;
           if (action == "Take Photo")
           {
               await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
               if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
               {
                   UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
                   return;
               }
               file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
               {
                   PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
                   Directory = "Sample",
                   Name = "test.png"
               });
           }
           else if (action == "Pick From Gallery")
           {
               if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
               {
                   UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("PhotosNotSupported", "PermissionNotGrantedToPhotos.", "OK");
                   return;
               }
               else
               {
                   file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
                   {
                       PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
                   });
               }
           }
           else
           {
               return;
           }
           if (file == null)
               return;
            Stream s = file.GetStream();
           RestaurantImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
           {
               file.Dispose();
               return s;
           });
}
```

Comment: if you set BackgroundColor in the image element, it will color the space that your image is taken.. so if you set the backgroung to white for example, and the image as transparency, the white will fill the transparency area, but remind this.. if you upload an image with white leters, it wont be seen, so you end up with the same problem

Comment: My answer got deleted because it did "not provide an answer to the  question" even though we solved the first issue you had. It seems like the second issue of "not displaying when taking image from gallery" needs a separate fix. Is it not working on Android and iOS on simulator and device?

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais if i set background color white in image control the pick transparency image from gallery its taking black background automatically note show white color

Comment: @Saamer i checked various android device but same behavior

Comment: Can you update the question with the latest issue now, since we fixed the issue of the background when the picture is taken from a camera

Comment: @Saamer Okay i edited my question.

Comment: Can you also share your code of the page where the imageTapped function gets called?

Comment: Hello @Saamer, <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
    <local:CustomImage x:Name="RestaurantImage" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Aspect="Fill" Margin="5" HeightRequest="205" WidthRequest="205"/>
    <Image Source="icons_add.png" HeightRequest="55" WidthRequest="55" HorizontalOptions="End"VerticalOptions="End">
        <Image.GestureRecognize
   <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ImageTapped"/>
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
 </Image>
</Grid>

this in my xaml tapped backend method mention in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@saamer and @leo thanks for help me :)

I resolved my issue **"set background color when take transparency image from gallery"**, when i used **PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium** then it's set black background behind transparent image but if i used PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Full it's set transparency background behind transparent image.

this is my get image from gallery code :

```
private async void ImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           string action = await UserDialogs.Instance.ActionSheetAsync("PickPhoto", "Cancel", null, null, "Take Photo", "Pick From Gallery");
           MediaFile file = null;
           if (action == "Take Photo")
           {
               await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
               if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
               {
                   UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
                   return;
               }
               file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
               {
                   PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
                   Directory = "Sample",
                   Name = "test.png"
               });
           }
           else if (action == "Pick From Gallery")
           {
               if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
               {
                   UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("PhotosNotSupported", "PermissionNotGrantedToPhotos.", "OK");
                   return;
               }
               else
               {
                   file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
                   {
                       PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Full
                   });
               }
           }
           else
           {
               return;
           }
           if (file == null)
               return;
            Stream s = file.GetStream();
            s.Position = 0;
           RestaurantImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
           {
               file.Dispose();
               return s;
           });
}
```

Comment: That's very unexpected, even sounds like a bug. How did you figure that out?

Answer (score 1):

You can see if the effect is what you want

1.create a **CustomImage.cs** :

```
public class CustomImage:Image
{

}
```

2.create a **CustomImageRenderer** in Droid project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomImage), typeof(CustomImageRenderer))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
  class CustomImageRenderer:ImageRenderer
   {
     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
       {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
         if (Control != null)
          {
            ImageView image = Control as ImageView;
            image.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.Red, Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.DstOver);
          }

       }
   }
}
```

finally use **CustomImage** load image

Comment: Hello @leoI used your solution if i kept transparency background image in Resources-->drawable folder then <local:CustomImage Source="trans.png" /> then its working red color showing on image background but if i taking photo from gallery its set black color automatically in image background not showing red color i want to show red color

Comment: @Deepakyogi i saw your code above,you didn't use CustomImage,you still use the original Image ? you try to use like  `<local:CustomImage x:Name="RestaurantImage"/>`

Comment: Hello @leo i use custom render but when i editing my question replaced local:CustomImage to Image